# ¿Puedo crear un loop con muchos 'category_name' para usar una única plantilla personalizada?

Tags: wordpress, bucles, wordpress-theme

tengo una duda enorme. Comenzaré por mostrar mi página para dejar una idea de lo que tengo y lo que pretendo.

Ésta es mi página , la comencé a crear desde cero hace unas semanas, y como habrán notado ante mis constantes preguntas, soy novato en WordPress y si bien ya he comprendido algunas cosas, probablemente en otros detalles básicos (si se quiere) me surgen dudas.

Ahora que conocen mi página, les mostraré una sección en particular, [la sección de criaturas].
Esta página que conforma las páginas de mi menú (todas estáticas) corresponde a una plantilla llamada `t_page_criaturas.php`. El resto de las páginas principales, al igual que la actual, ha sido creada en el menú por defecto `"Páginas"`, no tiene ningún orden superior (ya que ella es la superior) y he seleccionado la plantilla personalizada en cuestión que corresponde a `t_page_criaturas.php`. Lo mismo para el resto de páginas que conforman mi menú, `t_page_achievements.php`, `t_page_items.php`, `t_page_magias.php`, etc. Por lo tanto cada una de esas páginas está personalizada, y es que el contenido de cada una es diferente y se muestra de manera diferente también. Creo que por ahí estoy haciendo lo correcto (creo).

Ahora bien, esa página [criaturas][2] muestra una lista de 20 tipos de criaturas. Cada una de esas 20 páginas ha sido creada desde el menú `"Páginas"`, con orden superior de `"Criaturas"` y usando una plantilla personalizada llamada `page-{criatura}.php`, donde `{criatura}` representa el nombre de dicha página, es decir `page-anfibios.php`, `page-acuaticos.php`, `page-aves.php`, etc, por lo tanto se da a entender que cada una de esas 20 páginas es personalizada, es decir, tengo 20 archivos `page-{criatura}.php` en mi directorio, uno para cada página (un loop en cada pagina para cada categoria). Cada una esas páginas contienen una tabla (idéntica en las 20 páginas) donde se irá agregando cada `criatura` según la categoría a la que pertenezca y algunos datos de esas criaturas, los criterios para añadir cada criatura a su página correspondiente están en el loop de cada una de esas 20 páginas, los criterios son (por ahora) `'category_name' => 'nombre de la categoría'` (cuando despeje la duda agregaré también el post_type, ya que crearé un tipo de publicación personalizada para las criaturas).

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'reptiles', 'posts_per_page' => 300 ) ); 
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
  ...
  ...
  ...
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Todo bien hasta acá, pero **¿cual es la duda?**

Como novato que soy en WordPress y en vista de que estoy debutando con la creación de un tipo de página algo complejo (al menos para mí), **me surge la duda de si lo he estado haciendo bien o no** (en cuanto a lo mencionado al principio y la descripción de cómo he creado cada página), y me preocupa también la idea de tener 20 páginas que tienen el mismo diseño, con la misma tabla, el mismo formato visual, pero con la salvedad de que cambia la categoría en el loop para cada página.

Actualmente me funciona bien el loop, a modo de pruebas he publicado entradas y les he asignado las categorías que corresponden y efectivamente cada entrada es publicada en su página de tipo de criaturas que corresponde... pero en este momento tengo 20 plantillas para poder mostrar los 20 loops que corresponden a cada criterio de selección y sea enviado a su página particular.

**¿Hay una forma más eficiente, o algun truco bajo la manga para quedarme únicamente con `una sola plantilla` para cada `tipo de criatura`?** Y no tener 20 plantillas **¿y que al mismo tiempo funcione el `loop` como lo hace actualmente para cada categoría?**

**¿Son necesarias esas 20 páginas sólo para poder diferenciar el 'category_name' del loop?**

**¿Puedo crear un loop que contenga muchos 'category_name' para así poder usar una sola plantilla para los 20 tipos de criaturas?** Y no 20 plantillas con 20 loops en total (1 para cada una).

Espero se entienda lo que trato de decir y no es mi intención ponerlos a leer demasiado, pero lo creí necesario para entender el contexto real.

Muchas gracias de antemano por su tiempo y colaboración.

### Acutualización

Debido a que el uso que pretendia darle a `category.php` no es el uso más indicado para mi intención de mostrar una lista de páginas estática dentro de otra, decidí cambiar los 20 archivos `category-slug.php` por `page-slug.php`, evidentemente son páginas personalizadas, exactamente son estas páginas (las 20 páginas de la sección inferior):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cual es el problema? El mismo. Quiero mostrar artículos de ciertas categorías en su página estática (es decir, en cada una de los 20 `page-slug.php` que tengo), el problema es que no se si hay un modo mas eficiente para no tener que usar 20 paginas personalizadas solamente por el uso del loop y el llamado a la categoría determinada.

He creado esas páginas personalizadas porque cada una representa un tipo de criatura (no categoría de `category.php` como tal, ojo), en las cuales estoy usando este loop para traer cada tipo de criatura a su pagina única, es decir, publicar todos los anfibios en la página `page-anfibios.php`, cada Demon en la página `page-demon.php`, y así con las restantes (20 en total):

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'reptiles', 'posts_per_page' => 300 ) ); 
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
  ...
  ...
  ...
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Entonces, si bien el diseño de la página es exacto para todas las 20 que tengo, el loop es distinto para cada una, ya que cada loop es para cada tipo de criatura.

Lo que quisiera es crear un solo page-slug.php personalizado con el formato que estoy usando en las otras 20 pero con la salvedad de un loop "diferente" que en vez de tomar solamente una categoría de selección, lo haga con varias, es decir, con las 20 categorías de selección y las distribuya cada una a donde debe ir ¿donde debe ir? pues, de preferencia en un solo page-slug.php y NO en uno de los 20 que ya tengo.

¿Agregar 20 loops (1 por cada tipo de criatura) en un sólo archivo `page-nombre.php` personalizado es posible?

No se si me explico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente no necesitas las plantillas, `category-{category-name}.php`, esto se hace cuando quieres que una categoría especifica tenga un diseño diferente, si todas las categorías tendrán el mismo diseño, entonces usa solo una plantilla, la plantilla category.php y dentro de ella agregar tu diseño, en cuanto al loop, no es necesario usar `WP_Query` y especificar el `'category_name' => 'name',` ya que el archivo `category.php` automáticamente recibe el request de la categoría actual por lo que basta con tener un loop básico, por lo general se usa un query cuando quieres obtener datos fuera de sus plantillas, como en el home.php o index.php

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Y hacer una llamada al nombre de la categoría actual con `<?php single_cat_title(); ?>`

Anexo a eso, también puedes usar condicionales para saber si es o no una categoría, usando por ejemplo, la función `is_category()`

Comment: Gracias por responder Jefferzon. Lo que mencionas es correcto, de hecho así tengo mi category.php, y dado que la función real sería lo que tu mencionas, decidí cambiar esas páginas a page-{slug}.php que a mi parecer sería lo más correcto en vez de usar 20 categorías para mostrar contenido que no debiera ser mostrado en category.php, al menos no del modo que yo pretendía hacerlo (en mi desconocimiento pretendía usarlo como una página estática). Ahora bien, la misma pregunta pero ahora con page-{slug}.php ¿hay forma de hacer lo que mencioné en la publicación pero con page.php?

Comment: acabo de actualizar la publicación y también estoy probando algunas cosas en mis archivos que al parecer se acercan a lo que pretendo. Voy a elegir tu respuesta ya que de verdad me ayudó a despejar la duda de las categorías y el uso incorrecto que yo les estaba dando. Ahora mis categorías se muestran en una pagina de categorías y la información estática en sus paginas estáticas. Ante la duda volveré a preguntar por acá, así que muchas gracias de nuevo por tu tiempo y tus conocimientos, de verdad me ha ayudado mucho a entender cada vez un poco más todo esto.

Comment: Aplica para todas las plantillas de pagina, single, category, slug, etc.